# how can I implement a flutter if condition for a local user authentication?

Tags: flutter

I am trying to make a simple login condition based on a single value, but there's a problem somehow, I couldn't fix it.

and here is my code:

```
  home: Scaffold(
    body: Center(
      child: AlertDialog(
        title: TextField(
          controller: usrname,
          decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: "UserName"),
        ),
        content: TextField(
          controller: usrpass,
          decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: "Pass"),
        ),
        actions: [
          ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                if (usrname.toString() == "John") {
                  // Get.to(HomePage());  

                  return print("signed in");
                } else {
                  print("ERROR");
                }
              },
              child: Text("sign in"))
        ],
      ),
      // child:
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: Please clarify what the problem is

Comment: I want if the condition is true to navigate me to the homePage(); widget.

but it doesn't even print the value nonetheless navigating me to any desired widget

Comment: do usrname.text, its already a string so you dont need to do .toString()

Answer (score 1):

> The TextField. To get the text entered in the TextField, you should use usrname.text.

```
  actions: [
    ElevatedButton(
      onPressed: () {
        if (usrname.text == "John" && usrpass.text.isNotEmpty) {
          print("signed in");
          // navigate to the home page
        } else {
          print("ERROR");
        }
      },
      child: Text("sign in"))
  ],
```